# Possible combination of rooms for a product

Tags: algorithm

I have a product with many kinds of rooms available and customizable. For exemple :

- rooms for 1 person
- rooms for 2 persons with a king size bed
- rooms for 2 persons with two separated beds
- rooms for 3 persons

When a customer order a product (a travel), he give us a number of participants (for example : 2 adults and 2 childs...)

I have to give the customer the ability to choose a combination of kinds of rooms. with our example, we should have :

- 4 rooms for 1 person
- 1 room for 1 person and 1 room for 3 persons
- 1 room for 2 persons with king size bed + 1 room for 2 persons with separated bed
- 2 rooms for 2 persons with king size bed
- 2 rooms for 2 persons with separated bed

And at this point, I don't know what to do !

Comment: Do you have special rules for child, like a child cannot be alone in one room, or child is the same as adult? Also in your given example, there is no combinations like 2 rooms for 1 person + 1 room for 2 persons, are these left out by purpose or just didn't list them?

Comment: No, I don't. just the rules below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem (with 2 dimensions, adults and kids), where your sum is the number of persons and children and the the elements are the rooms.

It seems though, your problem is fairly small (you won't have hundreds of room types, only a few of them, and each traveler orders rooms for few people), so a brute force to show all possibilities is a one possibility to solve the problem.

The idea will be to generate ALL such rooms in recursive way, and before showing a possibility to the customer - check it meets the demands.

The recursive algorithm will first "guess" if you want to use the current room type, and for both options - recurse for a smaller problem.

Java-like Pseudo code:

```
private boolean matches(List<Room> rooms, int adults, int children) { 
    //check if the current list of rooms satisfies the demands
}
private int numPersons(List<Room> rooms) { 
    int res = 0;
    for (Room r : rooms) { 
        res += r.adults;
        res += r.children;
    }
    return res;
}

//wrapper function
public void generateAllPossibilities(List<Room> roomTypes, int adults, int children) { 
          generateAllPossibilities(roomTypes, adults, children, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
}

private void generateAllPossibilities(List<Room> roomTypes, int adults, int children, List<Room> soFar, int i) { 
    //check stop clauses, a "good" match, or out of bound:
    if (matches(soFar,adults,children)) {
         showOption(soFar); //succesful stop clause
         return;
    }
    if (i == roomTypes.size() || numPersons(rooms) > adults + children) {  
         return; //failing stop clause
    }
    //"guess" to add the current room type:
    soFar.add(roomTypes.get(i));
    //recurse with that guess:
    generateAllPossibilities(roomTypes, adults, children, soFar, i);
    //"guess" not to add the current room type
    soFar.remove(soFar.size()-1));
    generateAllPossibilities(roomTypes, adults, children, soFar, i+1);
}
```